# Is the dative plural of anima animis or animabus?

Tags: noun

Some paradigms I have seen give the dative plural of anima as animis.

However, other word lists claim that anima, filia, famula and dea are irregular and that the dative and ablative plural are animabus, filiabus, famulabus, and deabus.

Which is right?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Both are correct, but there are limited use cases for -abus. The chief form used across all authors for all words ends in -*is*, as in *anima, animis* (fem. dat/abl. pl.).

The only two *general* exceptions are *dea* and *filia*, which regularly use the form *deabus* and *filiabus*, and were created (Sihler § 265.3.b) to distinguish them from their masculine counterparts of *deus* and *filius*. Words like *animabus* are [comparatively rare](https://latin.packhum.org/search?q=animabus) (and in the example of *animabus*, are almost wholly confined to a single late Latin author). [*Famulabus*](https://latin.packhum.org/search?q=famulabus) doesn't appear at all; it is always [*famulis*](https://latin.packhum.org/search?q=famulis).

Thus Allen and Greenough summarize it thus:

> But, except when the two sexes are mentioned together (as in formulas, documents, etc.), the form in -***īs*** is preferred in all but ***dea*** and ***fīlia***.

Comment: Perhaps comparing this to the business of *arcibus/arcubus* would be useful?

Comment: @JoonasIlmavirta Good suggestion. I have to run at the moment, but I'll circle back to it later.

Comment: Just one elaboration; animabus becomes a common though still not predominate form in later Latin. I got over 3,000 hits in the Corpus Corporum database.

Comment: Re: _almost wholly confined to a single late Latin author_, it seems to me it escaped its confinement later on in ecclesiastical Latin , where _anima_ is a rather common topic. At least, _miserere clementer animabus parentum nostrorum_ in the _responsum_ is on top of my mind when the issue shows up.

Comment: "Famulabus" does not appear in the classical corpus, but I came across it in an [anecdote recorded in a book from 1844](https://books.google.com/books?id=AdlUAAAAcAAJ&pg=PA136&lpg=PA136&dq=%22famulabus).

Answer (score 8):

The regular dative and ablative plural for first-declension nouns is *-is*, but in contexts where it's desirable to stress the gender, the alternative termination *-abus* can sometimes be used. This only happens when there's a masculine second-declension noun whose dative and ablative plural would be homophonous with the first-declension feminine.
Well-known instances include *filiis et filiabus* 'sons and daughters' (rather than the unhelpful *filiis et filiis*) and the fixed expression *dis deabusque* 'gods and goddesses', but you see it for any feminine form of a word that's typically more common in the masculine and liable to get confused for it, like [*equa*](https://latin.packhum.org/search?q=equabus) and [*mula*](https://latin.packhum.org/search?q=mulabus). It's not usually obligatory (except in the case of *deabus*), but it is more common than Allen & Greenough realised.

Note that it only applies to nouns referring to persons or person-like entities: *animabus* only ever means 'souls' or 'spirits', not 'breaths'—that would be *animis*.